# Middleware is returning back to login page

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, vuex

I am trying to sign up, everything is working well, but user state can not get in time to be object and middleware is returning me back to login page

Here my state, mutations and actions which related to signing up:

`store`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  user: false,
})
```

```js
export const mutations = {

  ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION: (state, { authUser, claims }) => {
    if (authUser) {
      const { uid } = authUser
      console.log('STATE_CHANGED', authUser);
      state.user = { uid }
    } else state.user = false
  },

  setUserProfile(state, userProfile) {
    state.user = userProfile
  },
  
}


export const actions = {

  onAuthStateChangedAction: async (ctx, { authUser, claims }) => {
    if (authUser) {
      await ctx.dispatch('getUserProfileFromDb', authUser.uid)
    } else ctx.rootState.user = false
  },

  async getUserProfileFromDb({ dispatch, commit }, userUid) {
    try {
      const response = await this.$fire.database.ref(`users/${userUid}`)
      const { data } = await axios.get(response.toString() + '.json')
      await commit('setUserProfile', data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
  
  
  async createUserWithEmailAndPassword({ dispatch }, userData) {
    try {
      const result = await this.$fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        userData.email,
        userData.password
      )
      const user = result.user
      if (user) {
        await this.$fire.database.ref(`users/${user.uid}`).update({
          uid: user.uid,
          name: userData.name,
          photo: process.env.DEFAULT_PROFILE_PHOTO,
          phone: userData.phone,
          email: user.email,
          orders: '',
          coupons: '',
          bio: ''
        })
      }
      $nuxt.$router.push('/profile')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
[
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',

      {
        config: {
          apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
          databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
          projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.MEASURMENT_ID
        },

        services: {
          auth: {
            initialize: {
              onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction',
              onAuthStateChangedMutation: 'ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION',
            }
          },
          database: true
        }
      }
    ]
```

`middleware`

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.state.user) {
    redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

After refreshing page I could see my profile page

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save user uid somewhere like localstorege and give it to payload every initialization:

onAuthStateChangedAction(localStore.getItem('uid'))

Like this